# Translate from cc command line to CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cmake, clion

I want to use cmake on my project but I have to define a preprocessor macro this way :

```
#if defined CONFIG_TEXTUI

void BoardView_init (void)
{
}

void BoardView_free (void)
{
}

void BoardView_displayAll (void)
{

}

void BoardView_displaySquare (Coordinate x, Coordinate y, PieceType kindOfPiece)
{
    BoardView_displayAll();
}

void BoardView_displayEndOfGame (GameResult result)
{
  // TODO: à compléter
}

void BoardView_displayPlayersTurn (PieceType thisPlayer)
{
  // TODO: à compléter
}

void BoardView_sayCannotPutPiece (void)
{
  // TODO: à compléter
}

#endif // defined CONFIG_TEXTUI
```

The problem is that the file compile with this : `gcc -std=c99 -DCONFIG_TEXTUI -DCONFIG_PLAYER_MANAGER_MOCK -o etape1 main.c board.c game.c board_view_text.c tictactoe_erros.c player_manager_mock.c`

How do I specify those options in cmake (-DCONFIG_TEXTUI)?

this is my actual CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(morpion C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(morpion main.c game.c board.c player_manager_mock.c board_view_text.c tictactoe_erros.c test_checkEndOfGame.c)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY DCONFIG_TEXTUI)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY DCONFIG_PLAYER_MANAGER_MOCK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocessor macros are defined with `add_compile_definitions()`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html#command:add_compile_definitions

In your case you need:

```
add_compile_definitions(CONFIG_TEXTUI CONFIG_PLAYER_MANAGER_MOCK)
```

Comment: thanks i din't know they are called like that i was looking for the term !

Comment: It always hard to Google something you can't name, right? ;-)

Comment: I know what you mean #frenchteam